# How can I attach JSESSIONID in cookies, while sending an http/https request to a tomcat server, through an Ionic 4 app running in browser?

Tags: tomcat, ionic4, jsessionid

How can I attach JSESSIONID in cookies, while sending an http/https request to a tomcat server, through an Ionic 4 app running in browser? the same is working fine when running through a mobile emulator or in a real physical device